# Multi-row dependent drop-down list stops working correctly when a row is inserted

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-custom-function

Multi-row dependent drop-down list stops working correctly when a row is inserted. I think I need a script so that the drop-down options in column B, that change depending on what drop-down option is selected in column A, still work correctly when a row is inserted. I don't know how to write a script to do this.

I followed the 'Multi-row dynamic drop-down list' instructions from this site: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/dynamic-dependent-drop-down-list-in-google-sheets/

The above instruction only work if you don't need to insert new rows. :-(

My Google Sheet is attached. See the help notes tab at the start. I have stripped out all unnecessary tabs and data.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H-v6Nc0B5t9zj6TvVZ7hAUhrlsrJJt3RHQY1860rfZ8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi. I don't think that this particular infospired solution can be fixed. For scripts [How do you do dynamic / dependent drop downs in Google Sheets?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21744547/1330560) has been a meeting place for discussing and updating techniques for dynamic dependant dropdowns since 2014. Have a look at the answer (and comments) by @MaxMakhrov.

Comment: I suggest that you read  [Help with dynamic dependent dropdown](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/158322/196152) a very recent Q&A on webapps. Look at the OP's spreadsheet then add the code in the answer by @JacobJanTuinstra. It certain overcomes the issue of inserting a new row into the dropdown column.