# Help with dynamic dependent dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-triggers

How do I change this dynamic dependent dropdown list script so it works with my particular Google Sheet.

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dropdown database")
  
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  
  if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){
  
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

      var makes = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
      var makeIndex = makes[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
      
        if(makeIndex != 0) {
  
      var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, makeIndex, datass.getLastRow());
      var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
      activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  
  }
  
}
}
```

I found this script from a solution posted here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/61515090/help-with-dynamic-dependent-dropdown?hl=en

I put this script into my sheet but I am not sure what I need to change on it to make it work in mine. I can see I need to change the name of the sheet "Dropdown database" to "GS" to work for my sheet, but I am not sure what else I need to change. The aim is to get the dropdown options in column B to change depending on what is selected from a dropdown in column A. I need to be able to insert rows in this sheet as well and for the script to still work.

Here is a link to my sheet.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xbt-7JTYmkPr0Wo0DnyjacQPnTya2y4Vx48IhS1Jh6A/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi.  two things 1) Volunteers don't have permission to access the data on sheet="GS names" (sourced by a link to another sheet). It might be better if you just copy/paste this for this question.  2) Would you please explain _your_ scenario in your question. Please don't expect that volunteers must read the linked question and answer as well as open and review your spreadsheet to understand your question.

Comment: @Tedinoz 1) Good advice - I have fixed this in my sheet. 2) Apologies, I thought I had explained it clearly in my question.

Comment: Hey, Kate. I only just noticed from the items in "GS names" that you're from the land down under AND you're in education.  Both are near and dear to me; let me know if you ever need any help.

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, thanks so much, I would love some help with building my Google Sheets (workbook), hence why I am posting my questions online. I have more questions to come. I help with kids learning from home including those with disabilities during COVID. We make videos for them from content already filmed and I am trying to make a Google Sheet to help the editors keep the new videos organised. I am doing this in my own time but I am not a coder so makes it really hard. I have already posted a reply to the current issue I am having with the code in the other part of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following code you should be able to do that

### Code

```
const onEdit = (e) => {

  // // before doing anything check if we're in the correct row, column and sheet
  if (e.range.rowStart > 2 && e.range.columnStart === 1 && e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'GS') {

    // set offset (column B)
    const oSet = e.range.offset(0, 1)

    // get validation sheet
    const valSh = e.source.getSheetByName("GS names")

    // get index 
    const index = valSh.getSheetValues(1, 1, 1, 4).flat().indexOf(e.value)

    // check index
    if (index !== -1) {

      // set column index
      const cIndex = index + 1

      // set last row in validation range
      const lRow = valSh.getSheetValues(2, cIndex, -1, 1).flat().filter(d => d).length
      
      // set range
      const valData = valSh.getRange(2, cIndex, lRow)
      
      // build validation
      const valRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(valData).build()
      
      // set validation
      oSet.setDataValidation(valRule)

      // set focus to offset range
      oSet.activateAsCurrentCell()

    } else {

      // clear data validation
      oSet.clearContent().clearDataValidations()
    }
  }
}
```

Left the code in your example file and I hope the comments in the code are self-explanatory enough.

Comment: ‘if (e.range.rowStart > 1’. Shouldn’t this be ‘>2’, since row#2 is part of the header.

Comment: @tedinoz made correction

Comment: This is a much better answer than the one by Tedinoz. Among other things: 1) uses Event Objects, 2) tests for activity on the correct sheet before any code execution; 3) gets the last row for the relevant "options" column `const lRow = valSh.getSheetValues(2, cIndex, -1, 1).flat().filter(d => d).length - 1` so that the end-of-column warning is not included as a dropdown option.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. I copied the sheet, put in the revised code and tested what would happen when 2 new Creative Class names were added in sheet GS names. See https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oKxsGyedAc6aGcGEIoKaQe3o_0kDxHWwaKFUBUz3--A/edit?usp=sharing

The dropdown options for Creative Classes now offered in Column B fall 2 rows short of the full range. Is this because the range needs to reach to the very last row - so needs to include the row called "zz. Insert blank rows above this row - don't use the Add button at the bottom of the sheet?"

Comment: I am not sure what to change to make sure the range always reaches to the final row of the list as required. FYI, new classes will always be added to Creative Classes, Creative Teacher and Creative Resources as we create more content. I don't mind if the end-of-column warning is included as a dropdown option if that needs to happen.

I also ran a debug on the script and  I don’t know what this means or if it needs to be fixed.
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ Code.gs:4

Comment: @Kate i removed the `-1` at the `const lRow` line. Now it will include the ZZ entries as well.

Comment: _The dropdown options for Creative Classes now offered in Column B fall 2 rows short of the full range._ @Kate, there's nothing wrong with the **original** answer. The reason Column B options are two rows short **of what you expected** is Validation values are NOT updated just because you edited "GS names". onEdit updates Validation values when **GS-Column A** is selected, but you selected GS-Column B so the new Validation entries were NOT updated. In summary: the "problem" (such as it is) is that the Validation values (sourced from "GS Names") are only updated by the `onEdit` script.

Comment: I can think of two solutions (no doubt there are more). 1) **quick-and-dirty**: after an edit to "GS names", edit the Column A value on "GS" to trigger the `onEdit` script, then edit Column A again and select the desired option; Column B will now include ALL of the options from "GS names" (and excluding the "zz" warning.) 2) **Script edit**: extend onEdit to also test for changes to "GS names"; if found then... do something :).

Comment: @Kate As discussed, there's a basic rule of one question, one answer. These new problems, important as they are, need to be addressed elsewhere. May I respectfully suggest that you delete the last few comments that deal with new issues (one that don't  directly relate to the scope of the question). May I also suggest that you "accept" Jacob's  answer.

Comment: I deleted my follow-up questions. Note: This onEdit solution works bar the following issues. 1) If an inserted row has the border changed afterwards, the data in the row will be deleted. 2) Newly inserted rows will not copy data validation (if any exists) in the columns from the above/below rows as it usually would prior to inserting this script.

Answer (score 0):

Things to modify

**1 - Define the spreadsheet**

Delete: `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();`
Substitute": `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();`

**2 - Identify the sheet containing the dropdown values**

Delete: `var datass = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dropdown database")`
Substitute: `var datass = ss.getSheetByName("GS names")`

**3 - Identify the sheet containing the dropdowns**

Insert: `var gs = ss.getSheetByName("GS")`

**4 - Update the `IF` statement for the layout of this spreadsheet.**

- the specific sheet name ("GS")
- column number is 1 since the first dropdown column is Column A (compared to the reference in which the first column of dropdowns are in Column 2 (Column B))
- row number > 2 since there are two header rows (compared to the reference in which there was only one header row and the dropdowns begin in row 2)

Delete: `if(activeCell.getColumn() == 2 && activeCell.getRow() > 1){`
Substitute: `if(activeCell.getSheet().getName() == "GS" && activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 2){`

**5 - Update "Makes" and "makeIndex" to something more relevant**

There are several lines of code affected. Refer to the summary for a full list.

**Summary:**

```
function onEdit(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var datass = ss.getSheetByName("GS names")
  var gs = ss.getSheetByName("GS")
  var activeCell = ss.getActiveCell();
  

  if(activeCell.getSheet().getName() == "GS" && activeCell.getColumn() == 1 && activeCell.getRow() > 2){
  
    activeCell.offset(0, 1).clearContent().clearDataValidations();

      var options = datass.getRange(1, 1, 1, datass.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  
      var optionIndex = options[0].indexOf(activeCell.getValue()) + 1;
      
        if(optionIndex != 0) {
  
          var validationRange = datass.getRange(2, optionIndex, datass.getLastRow());
          var validationRule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(validationRange).build();
          activeCell.offset(0, 1).setDataValidation(validationRule);
  
        }
  
  }
}
```